# (∀x(s(x) → ¬q(x)) ∧ ∀x((¬p(x) ∧ q(x)) → s(x))) → (∃x(p(x) ∨ q(x)) → ∃xp(x))

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Can someone please help me solve this problem in predicate logics?
I've been trying to take the antecedence and so I can conclude something but I didn't get anything...

Any kind of help is appreciated!
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What exactly have you tried thus far? I know you said "take the antecedent," but what specifically have you attempted after that, and where are you stuck?

Comment: Hint: We have $(q\land\lnot p)\to s$ and $s\to\lnot q$, but $\lnot q$ contradicts $q$, so $q\land\lnot p$ is impossible. That is, $q$ implies $p$.

Comment: @Karl
If ( q∧¬p ) is impossible, then I get (p v ¬q) . How did you get that q implies p and how can I use that to get the consequnce?

Comment: Reduction to Absurdity.  $$\begin{split}q(c), \lnot p(c), (q(c)\land\lnot p(c))\to s(c), s(c)\to\lnot q(c)&\vdash\bot\\\hline q(c), (q(c)\land\lnot p(c))\to s(c), s(c)\to\lnot q(c)&\vdash p(c)\end{split}$$

Comment: What's the problem?  All I see is a logic statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've been trying to take the antecedence and so I can conclude something but I didn't get anything...

Yes.  Do that thing (a conditional proof).

Just to check: the antecedent is $\forall x~(s(x) \to\lnot q(x))\land\forall x~((\lnot p(x)\land q(x))\to s(x))$ and the consequent is $\exists x~(p(x)\to q(x)) \to \exists x~p(x)$

That antecedent is a conjunction, you use your rule for ... *simplification* or *conjunction elimination* ... in whatever system you are using.

That consequent is another conditional statement you need to derive, so do another conditional subproof.

$\def\fitch#1#2{~~~~\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}\fitch{}{\fitch{\forall x~(s(x) \to\lnot q(x))\land\forall x~((\lnot p(x)\land q(x))\to s(x))}{\forall x~(s(x)\to\lnot q(x))\\\forall x~((\lnot p(x)\land q(x))\to s(x))\\\fitch{\exists x~(p(x)\lor q(x))}{~~\vdots\\\exists x~p(x)}\\\exists x~(p(x)\to q(x)) \to \exists x~p(x)}\\(\forall x~(s(x)\to\lnot q(x))\land \forall x~((\lnot p(x)\land q(x))\to s(x)))\to (\exists x~(p(x)\lor q(x))\to \exists x~p(x))}$

Now use your rules for existential, universal, disjunction, and negation.

Comment: I know that from the antecedent I can conclude 'the first and the second part' of the conjunction.I also derived the consequent as you said.Now my question is: what can I exactly do with the 'two parts' of conjunction that I got so that I can conclude that antecedence implies the consequence?

Comment: As said, "Now use your rules for existential, universal, disjunction, and negation."  So what rules of inference for these connectives may you use?

Comment: Yes,I think I got it.But there's a thing I think I'm not sure about...In this kind of exercises we start from assumptions which need to be 'removed'  later so that the proof holds as true.I did all you said, and I have 'removed' all assumptions, except the assumption $q$ . In which step  can the assumption $q$ be removed so that I can be 'released' from all assumptions and so the proof would be true?

Comment: Yes,I think I got it.But there's a thing I think I'm not sure about...In this kind of exercises we start from assumptions which need to be 'removed' later so that the proof holds as true.I did all you said, and I have 'removed' all assumptions, except the assumption  . In which step can the assumption  be removed so that I can be 'released' from all assumptions and so the proof would be true?

Comment: Discharge it during the "proof by cases" step.